# Creating a .txt File named with a .get method

Tags: java, get, writer

I am trying to build up a form. At the end of the form I'd like the save button to create a TXT file named after the surname the person entered in the form. 
I only succeed in creating a txt file with a defined name (that I choose) or a file with no extension that got the surname info. Here is the code, thank you all for the attention:

```
    Button btnSalva = new Button(shell, SWT.NONE);
    btnSalva.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            BufferedWriter writer = null;
            try {
                writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(text_1.getText()));

                writer.write("Nome" + text.getText() + "Cognome" + text_1.getText() + "età" + text_2.getText());

            } catch (IOException e1) {
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (writer != null)
                        writer.close();
                } catch (IOException e1) {

                }
            }

        }

    });
    btnSalva.setBounds(10, 799, 75, 25);
    btnSalva.setText("SALVA");
```

Comment: *a file with no extension that got the surname info*: isn't that what you want: *a TXT file named after the surname the person entered in the form*? If not, what do you actually want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if surname is your text_1.getText(), and you want a TXT extension, just change your line :

```
writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(text_1.getText()));
```

into

```
writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( text_1.getText() + "TXT" ));
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue writing:

```
writer = new BufferedWriter( new FileWriter( text_1.getText() + ".TXT" ));
```